# Java Error: java -v command throws errors

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, jar

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04.5 server and am trying to install Java.

Running java -v in console provides this error message:

```
*Unrecognized option: -v
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.*
```

Comment: Is `java -version` not `java -v`

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the command

```
java -version
```